# Table Data/Header value has lots of space affecting export

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html-table, export-to-excel

I am generating a table in MVC. I am using tableexport.js for the export. However, I discovered that while I export the file to Excel, it has a lot of unwarranted spaces that is from the html table. I have tried to style but it has not worked. See sample generated table data when I inspect in Chrome:

[image]

See table header below:

[image]

How can I get rid of the extra space generated by MVC which are not in the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem with the spaces not from the mvc application but by editing the tableexport.js file. I changed

```
 return $(val).text();
```

to

```
 return $(val).text().trim();
```

for the export types xlsx, xlsm, xls and txt. I then changed

```
$(val).text().replace(/"/g, '""')
```

to

```
$(val).text().trim().replace(/"/g, '""').
```

Trimming was able to get the output in an expected way. Hope this will be helpful to any person with this kind of issue.